# Store Document Reference in Firebase from HTML <select multiple> using Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I am trying to create an array of references with Vue.js + Firebase. In the SELECT INPUT using multiple, when I try to store, it (obsviously) create an array, so my reference doens't work. I understood why, but I don't know how to solve this. When the OPTIONS from SELECT enters un the field to go to Firebase, it grabs and Array, so my reference link looks like     'todos / Item1 , Item2 , Item3'     ... Sorry if it is a newbie question, but I just started with vue.js and firebase. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<form class="new-todo-form">          
        <label class="new-todo-label">
          Day and Hour
          <input v-model="date" type="date" class="new-todo-input"/>
        </label>

        <label class="new-todo-label">
          Participantes:
          <select v-model="participants" class="select-input" multiple>
             <option v-for="todo in todos" v-bind:value="todo.institution">{{todo.institution}}</option>
          </select>
        </label>       


        <button type="submit" @click.prevent="addTest()" class="new-todo-button">Add</button>
</form> 


addTest() {
      testsCollection.doc(this.date).set({
        id: this.tests.length,
        date: this.date,  
        participants: todosCollection.doc('todos/' + this.participants),
      })
      .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
    },
```

Error in Console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an array"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root> vue.esm.js:628
FirebaseError: "Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an array"
    FirestoreError index.cjs.js:352
    validateType index.cjs.js:673
    validateArgType index.cjs.js:574
    doc index.cjs.js:21267
    addTeste App.vue:481
    click App.vue:386
    VueJS 3
```

Comment: Looks like this is stemming from `testsCollection.doc(this.data).set({` what is `this.data`? Im guessing its an array but the `doc()` function is expecting a string that will be used as the documents id.

Comment: Sorry, it's "date" not "data" (because I translated from Portuguese to English), but this "this.data" is the Date it was created, so I can get this date on the document name in Firebase.